# Extending express.Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there a way to extend `express.Router` ?

I tried this :

```
class Test extends express.Router() {

};
```

But express throws me an error.

Any solution ?

Comment: Please, add the full stack trace to the question post.

Comment: maybe you got spelling wrong `Routeur`

Answer (score 7):

The right way to do it:

```
class Test extends express.Router {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.get('/', (req, res) => console.log('test'));
    }
};
```

When you write `express.Router()` (with parentheses) you already call the constructor and therefore you're trying to extend an object instead of class.

Comment: When trying to do this registration is not happening to app.use(route)! Can you please tell me if this has ever worked?

Comment: Didn't you forgot to create the object? ```app.use(new Test())```

Comment: How did you get this working? Would like to do it the same way. But  tslint says `Type '(options?: RouterOptions) => Router' is not a constructor function type`.

Comment: no workie: (sorry, linebreaks not working in comments)

 /// class Test extends express.Router {
 ///  constructor() {
 ///   super();
 ///   this.get('/', (req, res) => console.log('test'));
 ///  }
 /// }
 /// let test = new Test();
 /// console.log(`test instanceof Test:`,test instanceof Test); // false
 /// console.log(`test instanceof express.Router:`,test instanceof express.Router); // false
 /// console.log(`typeof test:`,typeof test); // function
 /// console.log(`test.constructor:`,test.constructor); // function Function(){...}

Comment: @ngfelixl did you ever figure it out?

Comment: This solution does not work in TypeScript. `Type '(options?: RouterOptions) => Router' is not a constructor function type.ts(2507)`

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that because `express.Router` is a function. I haven't found how to extend a class with the function. But you can use an approach how this http://brianflove.com/2016/03/29/typescript-express-node-js/ or use standard approach with ES2015:

```
import * as express from 'express';

let router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

export = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
function My_Router() {
    return express.Router.apply(this, arguments);
}

var myRouter = new My_Router();
```

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me, I don't know English at all. Thanks to Google Translate ...

The constructor function should return a perfect (function, in fact) object of a router.
You can add to this object, whatever you want, or change it as you wish.
Each interface will have a new router object, of course.

It is also necessary to determine the prototype of the constructor function. This happens in line 6.

```
const Router = require("express").Router;

const myRouter = function () {

    const router = Router();
    Object.setPrototypeOf(Router, myRouter);

    router.myGet = function (path) {

        router.get.call(this, arguments);
        console.log("is my get function!!");

    };
    return router;
};

const router_custom = new myRouter();

router_custom.myGet("/", (req, res) => {

    res.send("hay!!");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**May be something like this would help**

```
 class YourController extends express.Router{
    constructor(){
        super()
        
        this.get("/", (req, res)=>{
            //do somthing
            res.send("return something");
        })
        
        this.get("/:id", (req, res)=>{
            //do something
            res.send("return something);
        })
    }
}

module.exports = new YourController();
```

Use It As :

```
const yourExtendedRouter = require("../controllers/YourController")

router.use("/base-url", yourExtendedRouter)
```